# openCV3: Not getting the expected output on morphologically transforming an image in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.6, opencv3.3

I am trying to do top hat morphological transformation to an image but not getting the expected output for some reason.

```
# Top Hat: difference between input image and opening
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/25 
tophat = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, kernel)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray'),plt.title('Original')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(tophat, cmap='gray'),plt.title('Top Hat')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

What is expected

[image: What is expected]

What I am getting

[image: What I am getting]

EDIT: Added the kernel.

Comment: I don't see the value of `kernel`. Do you get the same results regardless of the value of that variable?

Comment: Please upload your input file and post a runnable code(the `kernel` value).

Comment: updated the kernel.

Comment: Image that I am using: https://imgur.com/46HqmQZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, ksize=(9,9))
tophat = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, kernel)
```

[image: result]

**Edit:**

For details please read the following:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html

https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gac342a1bb6eabf6f55c803b09268e36dc

[Iterations vs. Kernel Size in Morphological Operations (OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070004/iterations-vs-kernel-size-in-morphological-operations-opencv)

Comment: this worked but may I know what exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to normalize your kernel?
Try removing the division by 25 from the kernel.

Morphological kernels are supposed to be consist of "ones" and "zeros". Therefore, no normalization is required. It will work fine with type CV_8UC1 as well.

Comment: maybe you need to adjust the size of your kernel

Comment: What is your image size? If its too big your kernel might be too small and therefore not doing anything to the MORPH_OPEN operation.

Comment: [TOP_HAT = SRC_IMG - MORPH_OPEN ]  if your MORPH_OPEN is the same as your SRC_IMG, then your result will be a blank image

Comment: Some documentation would help solidify your points from "try removing" to "remove" and so on. You are correct---the OP should have a binary kernel of `uint8` type.